# Why didn’t Rama shout words of assurance after Mareecha mimics his voice?

Tags: ramayana

Just as Mareecha is about to die, in a moment of brilliant trickery, he mimics Rama and shouts, “Alas Sita! Alas Lakshmana!”

> स प्राप्त कालम् अज्ञाय चकार च ततः स्वरम् |
> सदृशम् राघवस्य एव हा सीते लक्ष्मण इति च || ३-४४-१९

This worries Rama as he wonders what Sita will think of it.

> हा सीते लक्ष्मण इति एवम् आक्रुश्य तु महा स्वनम् |
> ममार राक्षसः सो अयम् श्रुत्वा सीता कथम् भवेत् || ३-४४-२४

But couldn’t Rama himself shout words to reassure Sita and Lakshmana and explain the situation?
Or did Mareecha canonically have the ability to shout very loudly?

Comment: Verse 8. Took him too far so obviously Maricha has the ability to shout loudly. Also to assure them, Rama would have to utter a sentence, the impact of which is not as loud as two names. Also he has clearly instructed Lakshmana not to leave, so he just thought that (verse 24) they’d be anxious hearing this sound, but didn’t think it was necessary to shout back.

Comment: In asking why something couldn't have ocurred, you are asking for opinions.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda The other possibility being Mareecha having the ability to loudly speak. I am asking if it is documented.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting"
[image: From Valmiki Ramayana]

Mareecha in his past history had supernatural powers as a rakshasa, where Shri Ram uses the powers of a mortal man, weapons, mantras etc.
Though worried he was ignorant of the plot to kidnap Sita. Thus he could not intervene in the way , we would wish as readers of the katha.